# Run custom executable with QProcess exiting immediately with exit code 1

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I need to run a custom executable in my application. I have the following code to run my process:

```
QFileInfo fiUpdator(updatorLocation);
if(!fiUpdator.isExecutable()) {
    qWarning() << "Maintenance Tool is not an executable";
    return;
}

qDebug() << "Starting updator app";
QString pid = QString::number(qApp->applicationPid());
QString appName = qApp->applicationName();

QProcess *p = new QProcess;

connect(p, &QProcess::started, this, [this](){
    qDebug() << "Updator Process Started";
});

connect(p, &QProcess::errorOccurred, this, [this](QProcess::ProcessError error){
    qDebug() << "Error Occurred : " << error;
});

connect(p, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished), this, [this, p](){
    qDebug() << "Finished Updator Process";
    QString str("Exit [" + QString::number(p->exitCode()) + "] " + p->exitStatus());
    qDebug() << str;
});

connect(p, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, this, [this, p](){
    QByteArray ba = p->readAllStandardError();
    qDebug() << "Error:\n" << QString::fromUtf8(ba);
});

connect(p, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, this, [this, p](){
    QByteArray ba = p->readAllStandardOutput();
    qDebug() << "Output:\n" << QString::fromUtf8(ba);
});

connect(p, &QProcess::stateChanged, this, [this](QProcess::ProcessState newState){
    qDebug() << "State Changed : " << newState;
});

p->start(
            updatorLocation,
            QStringList()
                << pid
                << appName
                << newFilePath
                << oldFilePath);
```

The application (a qt console application) runs as expected using

```
start "" "C:\Path\To\AwesomeConsoleApp.exe"
```

which briefly opens a new CMD window with the coded output, alternatively opening `cmd.exe` and running

```
C:\Path\To\AwesomeConsoleApp.exe
```

displays the output to `stdout` in the same `cmd` window.

The process signal fire as follows:

1. `stateChanged Starting`
2. `stateChanged Running`
3. `QProcess::started`
4. `stateChanged NotRunning`
5. `QProcess::finished` : output `Exit[1] 0`

I tried replacing the `.exe` to launch with `C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe` and it launched with no problem.

Does this mean there is something wrong with my custom executable?

Comment: QProcess::ExitStatus 0 means that The process exited normally. 
May be executable is reacting to arguments with exit code 1. Try to print all arguments and run executable with them manually.

Comment: @uni got it resolved, see posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Thought of deleting the question but incase it could be of use, I will post an answer which may help someone in future.*

The problem was not in the calling application code or the called application's code (i.e. the `MaintenanceTool` as shown above). Instead, it was a problem with the `MaintenanceTool` privileges.

So, my `MaintenanceTool` requires **administrative privileges** to execute. My calling application does not run with Administrative proviledges, but my `MaintenanceTool` does. For this, I was using [QProcess](https://forum.qt.io/topic/64378/call-another-application-with-administrator-priviliges) to facilitate launching the `MaintenanceTool` application.

***Note***: To gain administrative priviledges, I used [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/64378/call-another-application-with-administrator-priviliges) as inspiration to get mine working.

I tried combinations of the following with `QProcess`, **note that none of these worked for running an app as admin**!

```
QProcess::startDeteched("cmd.exe", QStringList() << "/C" << "/path/to/mtool.exe -arg1 -arg2");

QProcess::startDeteched("cmd.exe", QStringList() << "/C" << "/path/to/mtool.exe -arg1 -arg2");

QProcess::startDeteched("start.exe", QStringList() << "" << "/path/to/mtool.exe -arg1 -arg2");

QProcess::startDeteched("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", QStringList() << "/C" << "/path/to/mtool.exe -arg1 -arg2");

QProcess::startDeteched("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", QStringList() << "/C" << "/path/to/mtool.exe -arg1 -arg2");

QProcess::startDeteched("/path/to/mtool.exe", QStringList() << "" << "-arg1" << "-arg2");
```

I also created a `QProcess *p`, added `readStandardOutput()`, etc (as shown in question) which provide `Exit Code 0`. Further, I also tried printing out all the commands to the application, and invoking them manually as params when debugging the `MaintenaceTool` application. Running it with [manual arguments](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-run-settings.html#specifying-run-settings-for-desktop-device-types) had the `MaintenanceTool` running (using Qt debug mode) and working as expected which had me quite confused (but did not show the admin privileges dialog popup - didn't notice at the time).

Looking into the `QProcess::startDetached()` actual Qt code, I finally came across a message `error string` of sorts (which was never sent as an actual output or `errorString`) but was stored in a variable. Essentially, it mentioned that it was unable to start an application that required Administrator privileges. Thus, I searched and came across the [ShellExecuteEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/shell/launch) example found [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/64378/call-another-application-with-administrator-priviliges/12).

**My Implementation** of `ShellExecuteEx`

> QString args = QString("\"%1\" \"%2\" \"%3\" \"%4\" \"%5\"").arg(pid).arg(appName).arg(logLocation).arg(newFilePath).arg(oldFilePath);
>
> LPCWSTR file = reinterpret_cast(updatorLocation.utf16());
>
> LPCWSTR arg = reinterpret_cast(args.utf16());
>
> SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {0};
>
> ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
>
> ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
>
> ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
>
> ShExecInfo.lpVerb =  L"runas";
>
> ShExecInfo.lpFile = file;
>
> ShExecInfo.lpParameters = arg;
>
> ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
>
> ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
>
> ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
>
> ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);

Using the `ShellExecuteEx` solved my problem and allowed the application to run without a problem, with `runas` admin dialog popping up when the application is launched.

*I hope this helps someone!*